# Phone/Tablet different button height

Tags: css, button, height

I have this link, that's styled as a button on mobile devices the issue I'm facing is that it looks different on phone and tablet. Is this because of the device resolution or something that I should fix via CSS. Here is my current CSS

CSS

```
border-radius: 4px;
text-align: center;
color: white;
padding: 10px 30px;
border: 0;
position: relative;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 15px 0 0 0;
display: inline-block;
-webkit-appearance: none;
font: normal 16px 'helen_bgbold';
line-height: 30px;
background: #00aeef;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #00aeef, #58c5c4);
background: linear-gradient(to right, #00aeef, #58c5c4);
```

Comment: use css media query. And yes it's because of the device resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css media query to change html control/element style depending on the device screen resolution.

***HTML :***

```
<button>Button</button>
```

***CSS :***

```
button{
    // default resolution style
}

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    button {
        // style for screen resolution of width 300px or less
    }
}
```

Change the browser size and see when width gets to 300px or less how your button adopt the style defined earlier.

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/qr4tep3b/)